# Execute TemplateUrl by a click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm beginner in Angular.js.

I want make Accordion like file manager in Windows (tree).
When I click (ng-click or bind click) on element of tree, I want load it's children with $http and build DOM-tree from it with use templateUrl.

Can I do this?

[Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLaUj.jpg)

Comment: how I can execute directive by click? Directive to not be started until a click

Comment: Search or learn more. https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-directives-talking-to-controllers . Maybe this can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do is:
After you have thought about the layout of your tree view. Design a special directive for this purpose. This directive would have ng-click and also ng-repeat to insert the same directive.

```
<node ng-click="generateChildren()" objref="parent">
  <node ng-if="parent.activate && parent.children" ng-repeat="nodechild in parent.children" objref="nodechild">
  </node>
</node>
```

objref is the attribute to custom directive "node", then populate the parent.children object using $http ajax request "on click" of the node.
You need to have relevant CSS to handle the tree structures.
Hope this is more informative. Please let me know if you do not understand something.